# Efectos detectados en el cambio del diseño del sitio en español:

Tags: soporte, bug

con el cambio del diseño del sitio en español al ingresar a mi perfil en la seccion (no link/tab) de reputación me aparece esto vacío:

[image]

Al entrar a validar en el tab de reputación, asumo que debe ser las etiquetas de wiki que envié a edición:

[image]

**Si ven hay dos problemas:**

1. en la sección de reputación esta vacío, no se sabe por que ocurre el cambio de reputación.
2. en el `tab` de `reputación` solo dice wiki de etiqueta a esto se le puede concatenar la etiqueta edita?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Me han dado respuesta en META SE y se las comparto traducida:**

[Link Original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372834/925996)

---

El error que encontró se informó en esta respuesta [+2 para Wiki Tag Edit no muestra texto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372600). (El título de la respuesta fue tomado del [index post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698).)

Plantea una pregunta muy válida:

> Me preocupa que quiera ayudar informando algo y que **la barrera del idioma (...) ¿Cómo puedo determinar si esta publicación ya ha sido informada por otra persona?**

En tales casos, debe buscar por palabras clave (etiqueta, wiki, edición, reputación) usando la publicación de índice o usando la función de búsqueda para la pregunta, p. [`inquestion:372049 etiqueta wiki editar reputación`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion:372049+tag+wiki+edit+reputation) y reduciendo los resultados a partir de ahí.

> Idioma inglés para expresar e interpretar los mensajes; **Me preocupa**

Hay hablantes de muchos idiomas en el sitio e intentamos trabajar con otros carteles editando, aclarando, explicando. Así que, por favor, no se preocupe por la barrera del idioma al participar. En este caso, limite su búsqueda usando las palabras clave para asegurarse de que su publicación no sea un duplicado y la comunidad lo ayudará con todo lo demás.

> ¿Los errores encontrados en el sitio en español son los mismos que los reportados en Meta.SE?

Sí, estos cambios en el software de SE se implementaron en toda la red.

[Saludos o/](https://www.google.com/search?q=saludos)